# Disable specific dates in Angularjs date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to disable specific dates in the date picker of `AngularJS`.

I am using `AngularJS-bootstrap` css for components.

The dates which I want to disable will be changing dynamically based on the selection of previous value in combo.

I believe `date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"` should work, though not sure.

**How can i do this ?**

Comment: Hello! did you find anything about disable specifics dates dynamically (like if you have a list of activities, you choose another activity then you disable certain day on the calendar cause this activity has nothing these days)?
thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the `Datepicker` directive from Angular-UI. The `date-disabled` attribute lets you disable certain dates (weekends for example). See this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/gGAU0L?p=preview

If you want to dynamically disable dates based on selection, you can use the `min` and `max` attributes and watchers. See http://plnkr.co/edit/W5pb1boMLOHZFnWkMU8o?p=preview

#### References:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: could I disabled only few dates based on selection?

Answer (score 7):

Note, as of now, in the newer version(from 1.1.0) onward of AngularUI Bootstrap, you have to use `datepicker-options` attribute to do the date disable as well as things like max/min date.

in the html control, add

```
datepicker-options="vm.dateOptions"
```

or `datepicker-options="dateOptions"` if you are not using `controller as` but `$scope` directly.

Then in your controller, define the dateOptions object.

```
    vm.dateOptions = {
        maxDate: new Date(),
        dateDisabled: myDisabledDates
    };  

    function myDisabledDates(dateAndMode) {
        return ( dateAndMode.mode === 'day' && ( dateAndMode.date.getDay() === 0 || dateAndMode.date.getDay() === 6 ) );
    }
```

!!!Notice!!! the function **signature** of the `dateDisabled` changed. Previously it accept a date object and a mode string. In the newer version, it is a wrapped object containing both.