# How to enable particular dates using angularJS datepicker directive?

Tags: angularjs, html, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to create a `Datepicker` directive in `Angular JS` where I want to enable only a few particular dates for the user.

For Example: I have a set of numbers `1,3,5,7` so I want to enable these particular dates in the `Datepicker` for each month.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Datepicker directive from Angular-UI. Check out this thread :

[Disable specific dates in Angularjs date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837789/disable-specific-dates-in-angularjs-date-picker)

If you want to create a custom datepicker directive in Angular :

Assuming you have the algorithm generating a datepicker, you can make a regular datepicker and put a ng-click on each day (using ng-repeat inside week/month) and check if the selected day is a member of your set of numbers in your controller.

You can also use ng-class="{{disabled: checkIfDayIsDisabled()}} on the day element in your html to gray out the disabled dates using css to make it more obvious for the user.

Here's an example how I would implement it :

in your js:

```
var enabledDates = [1,3,5,7];

$scope.checkIfDayIsDisabled(day) {
    if (!checkIfDayIsDisabled(day)) {
        // executes this only if the day is enabled
    }

$scope.checkIfDayIsDisabled(day) {
    return (check if day is in enabledDates);
}
```

in your html:

```
<div ng-class="{{disabled: checkIfDayIsDisabled(day)}}" ng-repeat="day in month" ng-click="selectDay(day)">{{day.date | date:'dd'}}</div>
```

in your css:

```
.disabled{
    // your gray out styling
}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Actually I need something like this data is coming to my controller in form of string so when I pass this string to a directive then it should split and disable those particular dates in the Datepicker.