# How to enable only particular dates in a month and disable all others with angular UIB datepicker

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

I am using a angular UIB datepicker in my project, I need to enable few dates in a month and then disable all other dates. For example, I need to enable the these dates: `10th jan 2017`, `17th jan 2017` and `27th jan 2017`.

For now I am able to disable all the dates in a  month.  All the enabled dates should be highlighted with a black color and it should not highlight the current date.

Here my plunker link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/1EDNrhPHCaxBQCh4hQwT?p=preview

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837789/disable-specific-dates-in-angularjs-date-picker

Comment: @svarog, first thing it is not a duplicate question and second thing for disabling the dates we have date-disabled predefined attribute and my question do we have any similar kind of attribute which only enables particular dates in a month.