# how to disable specific dats from angular datepicker

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

```
   var post1 = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Home/GetunAvailableDates",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: sub1,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        });

        var a = [];
        post.then(function (d) {

            if (d) {


                for (var i = 0; i < d.data.length; i++) {

                    a.push(d.data[i].valueOf(Text).Text)

                }
            }
            console.log("success");

        }, function (d) {
            $window.alert("Oops!! Something went wrong!!!!.");
        });
        this.selectedDates = a;
```

I'm currently working in mvc project.

I'm using AngularJs datepicker for my booking page. I need to disable dates which booking is unavailable. 
I retrieve dates from database  as list inside my `booking.js` file

My problem is how can bind that list of dates to angular datepicker. I tried so many ways but result was not good. guys help me how can i do that using angular.

Comment: Think this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837789/disable-specific-dates-in-angularjs-date-picker

Comment: thankx Saeed.At. i looked that but thats not i wont.i want to bind list of dates angular datepicker

Comment: Use other datepickers like https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker which handle your task easily

Comment: @DanushkaJayawardane Are you using jQuery date picker with Angular js?

Comment: yeah i tried . jquery date picker .but my other all data bind with angular  and jquery not  work  properly with angular thats why im trying to bind this list of dates in angular